# How to add transactions in SQLAlchemy 2.0 Python

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, transactions

I have a function like this where I need to add transactions:

```
async def actualize_objects(objects, object_repository) -> None:
    to_create, to_update = [], []
    await object_repository.archive_all()
    already_have = await object_repository.get_all_ids()
    for object in objects:
        if object.id not in already_have:
            to_create.append(object)
        else:
            to_update.append(object)

    await object_repository.create_all(to_create)
    await object_repository.update_all(to_update)
```

It accepts objects and updates information about them in the database.
The `await object_repository.archive_all()` step should only be performed if you are sure that all other steps will also be executed. How can I add a transaction so that if the rest of the code fails, the database is rolled back to its original state?

I'm trying to do it this way, but it doesn't work and the database doesn't roll back.
I am using SQLAlchemy 2.0, Postgres database.

```
async def actualize_objects(objects, object_repository) -> None:
    await object_repository._session.begin_nested()
    try:
        to_create, to_update = [], []
        await object_repository.archive_all()
        already_have = await object_repository.get_all_ids()
        for object in objects:
            if object.id not in already_have:
                to_create.append(object)
            else:
                to_update.append(object)
        await object_repository.create_all(to_create)
        await object_repository.update_all(to_update)
    except Exception as error:
        print('ошибка')
        await object_repository._session.rollback()
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `async with` statement for transactions this way you can be sure that it will be committed if everything goes well, otherwise, it will be rolled back. Lets also add an raise statement in case there is an error we need to propagate.

edit: there might be a problem with `rollback()`

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession

async def actualize_objects(objects, object_repository) -> None:
    async with object_repository._session.begin():
        try:
            to_create, to_update = [], []
            await object_repository.archive_all()
            already_have = await object_repository.get_all_ids()
            for object in objects:
                if object.id not in already_have:
                    to_create.append(object)
                else:
                    to_update.append(object)
            await object_repository.create_all(to_create)
            await object_repository.update_all(to_update)
        except Exception as error:
            print('Error:', error)
            raise
```

Comment: This code gives this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't operate on closed transaction inside context manager. Please complete the context manager before emitting further commands.`

Comment: I modified my answer

Comment: I figured out what the mistake is. The fact is that in my function I call other functions that contain `session.commit()` construction. What should I do? I cannot override these functions as they are used in other objects.

Comment: Pass a flag to those functions that control whether they should commit or not

Comment: it's a good idea, but I don't think it's a good coding style